# Checking user group membership in permission_required

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin, django-views

How would I check if a user is a part of a group inside the `permission_required` decorator?

This is what I have currently but it doesn't seem to check it..

```
@permission_required(['user.is_super_user', "'NormalUser' in user.groups.all"], raise_exception=True)
```

This is supposed to check whether the user is a super user OR the user is part of the group `NormalUser` but when I try to access the site it just give me a 403 error when the user is part of the `NormalUser` group.

Is there a way I can get this done? I only want to use `permission_required` decorator, nothing else :S

Comment: "I only want to use permission_required decorator, nothing else :S" why?

Comment: As the name implies, `permission_required` checks if the current user has a given _permission_ (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) for this. The `permission_required` decorator checks permissions. It doesn't make sense to use it here.

First, you need to define a test function that returns True if the user is a superuser or is in the `NormalUser` group:

```
def superuser_or_normaluser(user):
    return user.is_superuser or user.groups.filter(name='NormalUser').exists()
```

Then you can use that test function with the `user_passes_test` decorator.

```
@user_passes_test(superuser_or_normaluser, raise_exception=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can pass a perm check like the latter in your list, that's essentially trying to execute some python code, which won't work.

It would be handy to understand what your use case actually is, but if you strictly only want to use the permission_required decorator (instead of very simply creating your own decorator that does precisely what you want, or using the 'user_passes_test' decorator which seems more appropriate), then I would suggest you should [add a custom permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions) somewhere in your system, add that as a permission of the 'Normal User' Group that you have created, and then just test (using permission required) the presence of that permission.

Depending on your use case will determine where you create this new permission.  Perhaps it's on a UserProfile type object ...